How to delete cart items for a specific user after stripe checkout session api
I have added the stripe payment integration, redirection is working fine on return url. But don't know how to keep track of the cart items to delete after successful payment.
for creating checkout session from backend
const payment = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.userId);
    console.log(req.body);
    const products = req.body;

    const lineitems = products.map((product) => ({
        price_data: {
            currency: "inr",
            product_data: {
                name: product.product.name,
            },
           
            unit_amount: product.product.price * 100,
        },
        quantity: product.quan
    }));

    try {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            line_items: lineitems,
            mode: "payment",
            success_url: "http://localhost:3000/successful-payment?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cart",
        });

        if (session) {
            console.log(session);
            // Assuming you have a function to delete cart items
            await deleteCartItems(req.params.userId); // Call your delete cart items function here
            return res.status(200).send({
                session
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error processing payment:", error);
        return res.status(500).send({ error: "Payment processing error" });
    }
}

for success page backend api
'const payment_status= async(req,res) =>{

const session_id = req.params.session_id;
console.log(session_id);
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
    session_id
  );
console.log(session);
}
'

